# Offer a sun icon rather than a snowflake for Summer Bash

Tags: feature-request, design, winter-bash, icons

If Stack Exchange is going to demonstrate more "hemispheric appropriateness" by allowing "Winter Bash" to be toggled to "Summer Bash", should there be an option in our profile settings to allow us to replace the snowflake icon with a sun icon in the top right corner of the webpage?

Obviously, this is not a mission critical feature, but it would be easy to implement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is as good a time as any to talk a bit about our early-days thoughts for this theme.

Originally, the plan was to do exactly what you say - have your choice of summer or winter bash persist across the network and change the icon to be a sun or a snowflake... and we had other cool ideas, too - such as making summer/winter versions of hats.

So, for example, a summer hat might be a glass of lemonade while the winter version would be an identically-shaped glass of hot cocoa or, maybe a sand castle hat would become an identically-shaped snow castle hat. The idea being, that if you earned a hat, you could actually get two versions of the hat but which version someone saw would depend on whether they had opted for winter or summer bash theming. And, because the artwork was identically-shaped, the placement would still be correct regardless of which someone was viewing.

We were all really excited about this idea when we left our ideation session but when it came down to actually building it, it was too complex to do in the time we had. It's too bad because it *would* have been super cool and fun and we would have loved to do it.

So, kudos to you for thinking of this and giving me a chance to talk about it a little.

Comment: Should this question be `[status-deferred]` for another Winter Bash?

Comment: You mean summer bash 

Comment: Feel free.  Ollie already prevented my clean question hat.

Comment: We have been changing the themes each year more recently so it's unlikely we would repeat this next year. As such, there's not really an appropriate status tag. I don't really like declining it. @RafaelTavares

Comment: Honestly, that sounds cool, but it's *way* too complicated for a bit of one-off, once-a-year "fun". I, personally, would not prioritize implementing this even for future years.

Comment: Considering it's already a problem getting themes done for sites that graduate and that this has been a problem for the past years, I imagine this will be tabled until those problems are tackled. As it should be.